# android setOnTouchListener change multi items

Tags: android

I have number of TextViews for which I want to change the color for all items as user drags cursor on them in one click.

I used `setontouchlistener`, but this method calls the action only for first button. Is there anyway to do for all in the same click when slide over them holding mouse?

This my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4,tv5;
    Button bu,bu1,bu2;


    MyTouchListener touchListener = new MyTouchListener();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv1.setId(1);
        tv2.setId(2);
        tv3.setId(3);
        tv4.setId(4);
        tv5.setId(5);


        tv1.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
        tv2.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
        tv3.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
        tv4.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
        tv5.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
    }

    public class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(v.getId()){
                case 1:
                    tv1.setTextColor(0xffff0000);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tv2.setTextColor(0xffff0000);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tv3.setTextColor(0xffff0000);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    tv4.setTextColor(0xffff0000);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    tv5.setTextColor(0xffff0000);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: post the code that you have tried so far

Comment: the code is just for example chuck

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want code to execute when the user either touches the screen or moves their finger across the contents of the a TextView while touching the screen.  Since all touch events are not by default passed down to children Views, one way to handle this is to override the activity's onTouchEvent method and check against the locations of each TextView.  I made an an example for you that does this:

```
pulic class SomeActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView tv01;
    ... 
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        // Get the center location of the TextView. 
        int[] tv01pos = {(int) tv01.getX(), (int) tv01.getY()};

        // Some debuging logs, may be deleted.
        Log.d("position TV x", String.valueOf(tv01pos[0]));
        Log.d("position TV y", String.valueOf(tv01pos[1]));

        // Get the width and height of textView 01 for calculating the right and bottom boundaries.
        int tv01Wide =  tv01.getWidth();
        int tv01High = tv01.getHeight();

        // Get the location of the touch event, event may be of type Donw, Move, or Up. 
        // Keep in mind there are a LOT of these generated.
        int[] touchPos = new int[2];
        touchPos[0] = (int) event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X);
        touchPos[1] = (int) event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_Y);

        // More debug logs.
        Log.d("position Tch x", String.valueOf(touchPos[0]));
        Log.d("position Tch y", String.valueOf(touchPos[1]));

        // Check if the touch event is in the boundaries of TextView 01
        if (    (touchPos[0] > tv01pos[0]           ) &&
                (touchPos[0] < tv01pos[0] + tv01Wide) &&
                (touchPos[1] > tv01pos[1]           ) &&
                (touchPos[1] < tv01pos[1] + tv01High)) {

            // A toast letting you know it's working.  Put your code here.
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "In TextView01", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you Derek you give a good idea to start I used eventmotion.getRawY() and getRawX to loacte the touch , your example need api 16 and above anyway, but used your idea to get it ,  it's worked after many tries thanks